# Query in Web browser control

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to automate a web application. What i'm trying to do is login to a website, select a dropdown and insert some Id into textbox and then click on a button and finally reading some text.

All is well when this is done for a single Id. Now I have a datatable containing say 100 rows. I want to loop and change the texbox value, click on the button and read new text.

Can this be achieved with web browser control? I shall post my test code tomorrow...

Any approach in right direction is highly appreciated. Thank a ton in advance.

```
if (this.wbProject1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            mFrameCount += 1;
            wbProject1.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "1");
            HtmlWindow win = wbProject1.Document.Window;
            if (win.Frames.Count > mFrameCount && win.Frames.Count > 0) done = false;
            for (int rowCount = dtCertificateNo.Rows.Count - 1; rowCount >= 0; rowCount--)
            {
                int loopCount = 0;

                DataRow drow = dtCertificateNo.Rows[rowCount];
                wbProject1.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[1].SetAttribute("value", drow["CertificateNo"].ToString().Trim());
                wbProject1.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[4].InvokeMember("click");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                if (done)
                {
                    string[] str2 = wbProject1.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.Body.InnerText.Replace("\r\n", "").Split(' ');
                    string[] str3 = wbProject1.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.Body.InnerText.Replace("\r\n", "|").Split('|');

                    for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (str2[i] == "Status:")
                        {
                            if (str2[i + 1] == "Unperfected")
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < str3.Length - 1; j++)
                                {
                                    if (str3[j].Contains("Reason:"))
                                    {
                                        DataRow drowFirst = dtReasons.NewRow();
                                        drowFirst["CertificateNo"] = drow["ID"].ToString();
                                        drowFirst["Reason"] = str3[j];
                                        drowFirst["Comment"] = str3[j + 1];
                                        dtReasons.Rows.Add(drowFirst);

// Here document inner text does not refreshes and remains the same for all the id's (holds the last one).

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    drow.Delete();
                    dtCertificateNo.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }

            if (done)
            {
                ExcelExport(dtReasons, "D:\\Test");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But this question isn't specific enough to get an actual answer, and there are many other posts that discuss the steps required to achieve this goal.

Comment: if you're doing this server-side (no javascript tag in your question) why can't you just make sure everything is in the state you want from the start instead of trying to simulate user-interaction?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I have added sample code of what i'm trying to achieve. I'm doing this in DocumentCompleted event of webbrowser control.

Comment: @EricLaw: could you please provide me ny link which decribes about the solution.